# hospital readmission within 30 days sql

Tags: mysql

i'm trying to write mysql from one table that contains only 3 fields (patient ID, admission start & admission stop). i need it to define if the patient was readmitted within 30 days (1 for yes 0 if not)

| Patient ID | Readmitted within 30 days |
| --- | --- |
| r753432343 | 0 |
| y839243422 | 1 |

Comment: Please provide sample data, expected output, table structure. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You could use exists logic:

```sql
SELECT
    PatientID,
    MAX(EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM yourTable t2
        WHERE t2.AdmissionStart BETWEEN t1.AdmissionStop AND
                                        t1.AdmissionStop + INTERVAL 30 DAY
    )) AS ReadmittedLast30
FROM yourTable t1
GROUP BY
    PatientID;
```